# Error running project in Visual Studio 2012 after encrypting web.config

Tags: encryption, web-config, visual-studio-2012

I have created a custom Protected Configuration Provider in order to encrypt 2 sections of our projects web.config using an X509Certificate, one of them being a custom section and the other being the connectionStrings section. It all works absolutely fine except for one annoying problem.

Each time I run the application in Visual Studio 2012 I get the following error message:

> The following error occured while getting connection string information from the configuration file.
>   "An error occurred loading a configuration: Could not load file or assembly FirstTitle.FastTitle.Security.X509ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9b660f7f535363a"

However the site then goes on to run absolutely fine and the Custom Config Provider is instantiated as expected and successfully decrypts the web.config.

If I install the assembly containing the provider into the GAC then the message doesn't appear however given that there are many developers working on this project I don't really want to have them to have to install the assembly into the GAC before they run the project.

Also I don't believe it should be installed into the GAC as it will only be used in this one project alone.

Further information:

My config provider is located in its own project called FirstTitle.FastTitle.Security.X509ProtectedConfigurationProvider which is signed.

The code for the provider is as follows (the interface is just a custom interface):

```
public class X509ProtectedConfigurationProvider : ProtectedConfigurationProvider,   IX509ProtectedConfigurationProvider
{
    #region Private Fields

    private const string _certNameConfigEntry = "CertSubjectDistinguishedName";

    private X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

    #endregion

    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        // Get the CN for the cert from the config.
        string certSubjectDistinguishedName = config[_certNameConfigEntry];

        // Get the certificate form the local cert store.
        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        try
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            // Find the matching certificate
            X509Certificate2Collection certs = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certSubjectDistinguishedName, true);

            if (certs.Count > 0)
            {
                certificate = certs[0];
            }
            else
            {
                certificate = null;
            }
        }
        finally            
        {
            certStore.Close();
        }
    }

    public override System.Xml.XmlNode Decrypt(System.Xml.XmlNode encryptedNode)
    {
        // Load the config unto an XML document.
        XmlDocument doc = encryptedNode.OwnerDocument;
        EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml(doc);
        eXml.DecryptDocument();
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }


    public override System.Xml.XmlNode Encrypt(System.Xml.XmlNode node)
    {
        // Load the config into an XML document.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        doc.LoadXml(node.OuterXml);

        EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
        EncryptedData eData = eXml.Encrypt(doc.DocumentElement, certificate);
        return eData.GetXml();
    }
}
```

The configProtectedData element within the web.config is set as follows (I've removed the name of the certificate for security reasons):

```
<configProtectedData>
  <providers>
    <add name="X509Provider" type="FirstTitle.FastTitle.Security.X509ProtectedConfigurationProvider, FirstTitle.FastTitle.Security.X509ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9b660f7f535363a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"  CertSubjectDistinguishedName="CN=NameRemoved"></add>
  </providers>
</configProtectedData>
```

As I say, everything works fine with the exception of this annoying message that appears in VS2012. I've been googling a lot to try and find an answer but to no avail. Can anyone help?